# Why didn't Loki fall into the Asgardian sea instead of falling into space (abyss) after the destruction of the Rainbow bridge?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-2011, asgard

In *Thor* (2011) after Thor shattered the Rainbow Bridge with Mjolnir both him and Loki were going to fall into space (abyss) before Odin arrived for their help. But in the movie we can see water (Asgardian sea) below the Rainbow Bridge during the combat between Loki and Thor. Once the bridge is shattered water gushes above the bridge and both the brothers were thrown up in air. When they landed down we can see both the brothers were going to fall down into space from the verge of the shattered Rainbow Bridge before Odin came for their rescue.

Were they both supposed to fall in water (Asgardian sea)? Because, initially there was water below the bridge prior to its destruction.